# JGraph has unresolved AttributeMap on precompilation

Tags: eclipse, jgrapht, jgraphx, jgraph

I am writing a first VERY simple class to see if my install can build something. So this is what I have

```
import org.jgrapht.ListenableGraph;
import org.jgrapht.ext.JGraphModelAdapter;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.ListenableDirectedGraph;

public class Some<JGraph> {

private Some() {
        ListenableGraph g = new ListenableDirectedGraph( DefaultEdge.class );

        JGraph graph = new JGraph(new JGraphModelAdapter( g ));
    }
}
```

I am working in Eclipse and I have `jgrapgt-core`, `jgrapht-ext`, `jgraphx` and `jgraphx-3.2.2.0` setup as user libraries.

My problem is when I try to create the `JGraphModelAdapter` I get the error:

```
The type org.jgraph.graph.AttributeMap cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

JGraphT uses the old JGraph 5 library for visualization. org.jgraph is JGraph 5, com.jgraph is JGraphX.

Replace the jgraphx libraries with those from JGraph 5. JGraph 5 is on Github [here](https://github.com/jgraph/legacy-jgraph5).

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was the case simply because I do not see any algorithms implemented in JGraphX.  It looks simply like a visualization library.  I was hoping for 'shortest path', 'sorting', that sort of thing.